# iOS: Detect long press without removing finger

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am using a UILongPressGestureRecognizer. I am wondering if anyone has ever figured out a way to trigger when the minimumPressDuration has been reached without having to lift their fingers. Basically, can we trigger the end of the gesture without having to remove our fingers? Can we just use how much time had passed?

Thanks,

Collin

Comment: I dont think you can, but making a custom Gesture is easy, if you want help I can post an answer showing how to di it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what the UIGestureStateBegan is for:

```
-(void)handleGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        NSLog(@"minimum duration elapsed");
    }else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        NSLog(@"user lifted their finger");
    }
}
```

Comment: @danh UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized is equivalent to UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded in value, and is only fired when the user lifts their finger

Comment: yes, indeed.  i'll remove my comment, and sorry for adding confusion.

Comment: awesome! I thought from reading the documentation that the Began state  was for when the user first tapped the screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.began` state ends when user lifts the finger, so the accepted answer is not correct for this problem. After some time I figured it out.
Answer in Swift:

```
var gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))

func handleLongPress(){
         //do something
         gesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
}

@objc func longPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
         if sender.state == .began {
                handleLongPress()
                gesture.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
      }
}
```

This will cause the gesture to stop tracking touch after `.began` state is received and re-enable it after you finish doing whatever you want to do after long press

This is very old question but I hope someone will find it useful